# Cannot open dll file,when i try to create a dll in vc++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll, compilation

[image]

The chinese under the highlighting line of compiling info bar means:

> encounted error when execute "linke.exe"

Like this, i want to create a dll, but encount error and i don't kown what lead to this!
It's a Win32 Dynamic-link Library in Project Tab, with project named "mydll", and the source files hierarchy you can see in the top screenshot,This is "mydll.cpp". while i am using win7 in Oracle VirtualBox, and my host OS is Ubuntu 12.04, i have no idea does virtual mechine system has some impact on this confused result.

SOS! and happy Thanksgiving!

[image]

Comment: is `mydll.dll` used by another process? For instance can you delete it?

Comment: is this visual c++ 6? Wow, that's a blast from the past

Comment: it is not being called right now, I try to make this dll, as a component, providng some essential algorithem implementation for a application.and the application is not running.

Comment: This is a bit of stab in the dark, but, try running visual studio as an administrator